# How to clear the screen and auto-mount device on startup?

Tags: cron, reboot, systemd-startup

I have a Raspberry Pi connected to my TV, which I use to read videos stored on an external hard drive.

I have 2 commands that I run everytime the Raspberry Pi reboots:

- This one, to clear the prompt that shows up on the TV: `sudo sh -c "TERM=linux setterm -foreground black -clear all >/dev/tty0"`
- This one, to mount the hard drive: `mount -L hard-drive /media/hard-drive`

I would like those commands to be automatically ran everytime the Raspberry Pi reboots, so I've added the following to my crontab:

```
@reboot sh -c "TERM=linux setterm -foreground black -clear all >/dev/tty0"
@reboot mount -L hard-drive /media/hard-drive
```

However, it doesn't seem to do the trick, because after a reboot, the prompt is still there on the TV, and the drive is not mounted.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Put the mount stuff in /etc/fstab. Put the clear screen stuff in ~/.profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To mount the hard drive on boot up you can just add an entry into `/etc/fstab`, something like:

```
LABEL=hard-drive     /media/hard-drive    ext4   defaults 0 0
```

Instead of `ext4` you may have to use the filesystem on your hard-drive.

To execute the clear command on startup just create a systemd Unit with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl --force --full edit clear-screen.service
```

In the empty editor insert these statements, save them and quit the editor:

```
[Unit]
Description=Clear Screen
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
Environment="TERM=linux"
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/setterm -foreground black -clear all >/dev/tty0'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Enable the new service with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl enable clear-screen.service
```

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm. Two details I found on my way to making it work: if the device contains an NTFS filesystem, even though `df -Th` reports it as `fuseblk`, `/etc/ftab` still expects `ntfs`. If the device might not be physically there at boot, then the options `defaults` should be replaced with `defaults,nofail`.